# Angular 5 binding material 5 DatePicker to form field

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am trying to bind an Angular materials 5 date picker to a form field, i am following the official tutorial [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) but there isn't any information about how to bind the calendar value to a field within a form, it could also be bound to a class attribute, but that also does not work.
My template is simply:

```
 <form #theForm="ngForm">
   .......Some fields.......
   <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="fixDate" placeholder="Choose a date" name="fixDate">
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fixDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #fixDate></mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>
 </form>
```

So this piece of template within the `<mat-form-field>` tags, consists of an input within a form, by giving it a `name`, i would expect it to be 'catchable' from the `.ts`, but it does not work, what i do in the `.ts` file is:
`(click)="saveReport(theForm)"`

```
`public saveReport(form: NgForm){
    if(confirm("Sure you wanna save?")){
      //Some non relevant validation
      let valuesFromForm = form.value;
      console.log(valuesFromForm['fixDate']);
    }
}`
```

This prints `undefined`, but other fields in the form work just fine, when you give them a `name` they are retrievable via the form object in the `.ts` file
Any advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using reactive forms the following works for me using *mat-datepicker*.

My **xxx.component.html** file looks for example like follows. (Very similar to yours accept the reactive forms bindings)

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Start" formControlName="date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

in the **xxx.component.ts** I import the reactive forms related targets *FormBuilder*, *FormGroup*, *FormControl*. And *Validators* if you want to validate. Then

```js
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = fb.group({
    date: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

[...]

save(data: YourDataType) {
  /* Here you go */
}
```

Now you should be able to grab *data.date* as your selected value not beeing undefined. At least it can be an empty string, which you can prevent by adding validators.
Of course you have to import the *MatFormFieldModule* and *MatDatepickerModule* from *@angular/material* and import it in your component related module.

Hope this answers your question properly and helps for solving your problem. Cheers!